# How to replace values at certain indices in a column based on presence of a string in values of that column (using dplyr and repeatedly with no loop)?

Tags: r, dplyr, pattern-matching

Example using mtcars:

```
data(mtcars)
mtcars$car <- row.names (mtcars)
```

In car column: I have car names listed as  "Mazda RX4", "Mazda RX4 Wag", "Datsun 710", "Hornet 4 Drive", etc. Assume I wanted to remove the model of the car and only leave the manufacturer e.g. "Mazda", "Datsun", "Hornet", also ***assume that the names are not formated to have manufacturer always as the first word***, so I can also have a name for the car as "ModelX Mazda", or "model Tesla XX", so I cant extract manufacturer as the first word of a string.

How would you go about this task, if you had a string that contained all the manufacturers names c("Mazda", "Datsun", "Hornet")?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is string of patterns, we can create a single string by collapsing with `paste`

```
v1 <- c("Mazda", "Datsun", "Hornet")
pat <- paste0(".*\\b(", paste(v1, collapse="|"), ")\\b.*")
```

then use `sub` and capture those patterns as a group

```
mtcars$car[2] <- "RX4 Mazda Wag" # // changed for testing
out <- sub(pat, "\\1", mtcars$car)
head(out, 5)
#[1] "Mazda"  "Mazda"  "Datsun" "Hornet" "Hornet"
```

---

Or using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
mtcars <- mtcars %>%
       mutate(car = str_replace(car, pat, '\\1'))
```

Comment: thanks! Could you please point me anywhere I can read about the "\\1" pattern?

Comment: @PavelShliaha you may check [here](https://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html)

Answer (score 1):

You could also use `str_extract` as shown below:

```
vec <- c("Mazda", "Datsun", "Hornet")

str_extract(mtcars$car, str_c(v, collapse = '|'))
```

Of course if you feel that the model for a given car manufacturer might contain a different car manufacturer, then you should wrap the pattern with boundary.
ie

```
str_extract(mtcars$car, sprintf("\\b(%s)\\b", str_c(v, collapse = '|')))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the fuzzyjoin package and do a regex_left_join

```r
to_match <- c("Mazda", "Datsun", "Hornet")

library(tidyverse)

df <- 
  mtcars %>% 
    rownames_to_column('car')

library(fuzzyjoin)

df %>% 
  regex_left_join(tibble(to_match), by = c('car' = 'to_match')) %>% 
  select(car, to_match) %>% 
  head
#>                 car to_match
#> 1         Mazda RX4    Mazda
#> 2     Mazda RX4 Wag    Mazda
#> 3        Datsun 710   Datsun
#> 4    Hornet 4 Drive   Hornet
#> 5 Hornet Sportabout   Hornet
#> 6           Valiant     <NA>
```

<sup>Created on 2021-05-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>